# Pass string[] as parameter on command line for Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm using a PowerShell script to execute `az cli` commands.
I want to wrap this command:
`az tag update --resource-id $appPlanId --operation merge --tags Tag1=test1 Tag2=test2`
The `--tags` argument is some kind of string array.

I created this PowerShell function:

```
function Update-ResourceTagsJustForResource {
    [OutputType([string])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string] $ResourceId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][System.string[]] $ResourceTags
    )
    az tag update --operation merge --resource-id $ResourceId --tags $ResourceTags
}
```

And I call it like this:
`Update-ResourceTagsJustForResource -ResourceId $appPlanId -ResourceTags Tag1=test1 Tag2=test2`
I get this error:
`A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Tag2=test2'`

When I call it like this:
`Update-ResourceTagsJustForResource -ResourceId $appPlanId -ResourceTags "Tag1=test1 Tag2=test2"`
I don't get an error, but only 1 tag is added:
`"Tag1": "test1 Tag2=test2"`

These options don't work either:

- `Update-ResourceTagsJustForResource -ResourceId $appPlanId -ResourceTags "Tag1=test1" "Tag2=test2"`
- `Update-ResourceTagsJustForResource -ResourceId $appPlanId -ResourceTags "Tag1=test1", "Tag2=test2"`
- `Update-ResourceTagsJustForResource -ResourceId $appPlanId -ResourceTags []{"Tag1=test1", "Tag2=test2"}`
- `Update-ResourceTagsJustForResource -ResourceId $appPlanId -ResourceTags ("Tag1=test1", "Tag2=test2").Split(',')`

What is the correct syntax to call my PowerShell command with an array of strings as a parameter?

Comment: `-ResourceTags "Tag1=test1", "Tag2=test2"` should work for sending a string array to the function, however, it looks like `az tag update` just wants a single, space-separated string there. In that case, inside the function do `-ResourceTags $($ResourceTags -join ' ')`

Comment: Thanks @Theo for your quick reply. As I mention in my post I already tried that option. It results in a tag called `Tag1` with a value of `test1 Tag2=test2`.
I missed your update. I just tried the `-join` suggestion but that also results in 1 tag with the second tag as value.

Comment: But did you read the second part of my comment as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

You can call your function like below(have modified yours a little):

```
$r = "/subscriptions/b83c-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/bojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/rithwik123"
$t = "Tag1=test1", "Tag2=test2"
Update-ResourceTagsJustForResource -ResourceId $r -ResourceTags $t
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'm using existing scripts in a new environment and the script had another wrapper around the `az cli` command. That wrapper was messing up the array.
I now run the bare `az cli` command and the proper parameter value and my script is working again. I'll mark your reply as the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you @Paul Meems